# Is there a difference between `ember serve` and `npm start`?

Tags: npm, ember.js, ember-cli, npm-start

What is the difference between the commands `ember serve` and `npm start`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what’s defined in your `package.json` file. As of the [current Ember CLI blueprint](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/365995ee714e6e8d1f8f6687eb3e6162895ee5b5/blueprints/app/files/package.json#L18), `npm start` is defined to resolve to `ember serve`, so there’s nearly no difference. You can change the definition of the `start` script to whatever you want, though, which might be useful if your application has extra startup requirements or flags.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, and in a fresh Ember app, `ember serve` and `npm run start` behave identically.

There are a few rare cases, e.g. if the Node version of your globally installed Ember CLI version differs from the Node version of the Ember CLI version defined in your project locally, in which `npm run start` and `ember serve` might not behave the same way.

I outlined such an example case in [this blog post "The difference between ember serve and npm run start"](https://dev.to/jayjayjpg/the-difference-between-ember-serve-and-npm-run-start-2m5p).